# How to CNAME a domain to "host.docker.internal"?

Tags: docker

I know "host.docker.internal" points to the host running docker daemon. I'd like to achieve the following:

```
services:
  xx:    
    extra_hosts: ["example.com:host.docker.internal"]
```

But I can only use a specific IP address in extra_hosts.

My question: Is there a way to do this?

Comment: there is always an option to start a [bind9](https://hub.docker.com/_/bind9) container as an internal dns server ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your docker version is **above 20.04**, then you could use next:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Detail see [this](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-772844305).

**Then you could use `host.docker.internal` to communicate with host, e.g.:**

```
$ docker run --rm -it --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway debian:10 ping -c 4 host.docker.internal
PING host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.064 ms
64 bytes from host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
64 bytes from host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
64 bytes from host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.095 ms

--- host.docker.internal ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 74ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.064/0.086/0.095/0.017 ms
```

Comment: host-gateway points to 192.168.65.1, but host.docker.internal points to 192.168.65.2. I can't CNAME example.com to host-gateway, it will break.